# Cant write more than one row in excell sheet using POI

Tags: java

I'm developing an app in java using POI, which writes data into excell sheet.
I want to write a new row when I have a new data (in order to assist the user to follow the data).
I dont want to close and reopen the excell file each time I have a new data to write.

The initilize code is:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(new File (excellFileName));
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");
rowNum = 0;

HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short)rowNum);
createRowColumns(rowhead, rowNum);
workbook.write(fileOut);    
rowNum++;
```

Each time I have a new data, I'm using this code:

```
HSSFRow rowMsg = sheet.createRow((short)rowNum);      
createRowColumns(rowMsg, rowNum);
workbook.write(fileOut);       
rowNum++;
```

(createRowColumns mehtod sets the data (in seperate cells in a new: rowMsg)
The problem is that I cant see any rows in the excell file, except the first row (rowhead , row #0).

What Am I missing ?
(Pay attention that I dont want to close and reopen the file each time I have data to write)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To write all rows you have to write to worksheet only once. So, you need to update your code as follows.

```
for(int index = 0; index < rowNum; rowNum++) {
    HSSFRow rowMsg = sheet.createRow((short)rowNum);      
    createRowColumns(rowMsg, rowNum);
}
workbook.write(fileOut);
```